# How to fix an apparent camera conflict in opencv with Python

Tags: python, opencv, camera

I have a system with 3 actual webcams and one "webcam"(actually a gvUSB2 - a USB converter from RCA jacks). When using capture software like OBS, I can access all cameras at the same time (although I do notice occasional glitching). When I try to do the same with openCV, the result depends on which cameras are plugged in, but it seems like I can only use openCV to open the gvUSB2 camera if only 1 other camera is plugged in. I don't get an error message if it fails, rather when I access the gvUSB2 slot I get a duplicate of another camera. Using Python3.7 and freshly installed openCV.

I've tried moving around the USB slots. The drivers should be up to date for the "webcam". Like I said, using capture software I am able to collect data from all cameras simultaneously, while I can't capture from the "webcam" at all in openCV.

My test program is very simple, I just rotate through the camera index values here(ie, 0, 1, 2, 3):

```py
import cv2
import sys
print(sys.argv[1])
s_video = cv2.VideoCapture(int(sys.argv[1]))
while True:

    ret, img = s_video.read()    
    cv2.imshow("Stream Video",img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
```

When the above code is run with 3 traditional webcams I am able to access all of them. However if the convertor "webcam" is installed, I get a duplicate image. IE, for all 3 traditional cams I will have 0, 1 and 2 showing the traditional images, and then 3 will be a duplicate of 2. On the other hand with just 1 traditional webcam installed, 0 will be the traditional webcam and 1 will be the correct image of the converter "webcam".

My thinking:
It seems like I am not overwhelming my USB system, because it can handle all the traditional webcams, and the resolution of the converter is much lower than the traditional ones (704x480 IIRC). My guess is a driver problem with the converter, and unfortunately since I am up to date, I may be out of luck.  The counter evidence for this is that a capture program like OBS IS capable of reading from all webcams, suggesting that this may be a problem with openCV (or more likely, how I am using it). I can't find any google posts coming within 10 miles of this problem, so I'm pretty stuck. Any ideas?